# How to create a JSON Object's element based on if it is null or not?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

```
     async homeApi(_source: any, _args: any) {
        const body = {
          door: _args.door,
          window: _args.window
        };
}
```

I have a typescript code like above where I create a JSON Object called `body` using `door` and `window` arguments.
Typically the body should be:

```
     {
    door: 3,
    window: 4
   }
```

What I want is if `_args.door` is empty/blank, the `body` should be

```
{window: 4}
```

It should not be:

```
{
    door: '',
    window: 4
}
```

Comment: Does `door: _args.door` not already do what you want? If it's undefined, it'll stay undefined. It won't just magically conjure a value out of nowhere.

Comment: I am sorry. I updated the question. the door element should be removed and shouldn't be blank.

Comment: Use a `for...in` and `delete` the properties you want according to that condition (btw, `undefined` is not `""`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to filter out the fields that are `undefined` or empty. You could do this:

```js
var data = {
   a: undefined,
   b: "foo"
 }
 
 Object.keys(data).forEach(i=>{
   if(!data[i] && data[i] !==0) delete data[i]
 })
 
 console.log(data)
```

Comment: This will delete properties with `0` as well, which seems to be a valid value to OP.

Comment: That's a good point. `0` is a `fasly` value. Let me update that.

Comment: Properties with value `undefined` will already be stripped when encoding to JSON, so the loop is not needed.

Comment: @Evert well, I guess `null or ''` (all falsy except 0) need to be accounted for as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object assign to get rid of the undefined object. However, for an empty value, you need to check and delete it. You can check below code.

```js
const _args = {
  window: 4
};
const _args1 = {
  door: '',
  window: 4
};
const _args3 = {
  door: 3,
  window: 4
};


homeApi = (_args2) => {
  const bod = { ..._args2};
  if(bod['door'] === ''){
  delete bod['door'];
  }
  console.log(bod);
}

homeApi(_args);
homeApi(_args1);
homeApi(_args3);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be creating object by taking `entries` and filtering according to your conditions:

```js
const data = {
   a: undefined,
   b: "foo",
   k:0
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([k,v])=>v || v==0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the fields that are `undefined` or `null` as follows:

```js
const data = {
  a: "bar",
  b: undefined,
  c: "faz",
  d: null,
};

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (data[key] !== null && data[key] !== undefined) obj[key] = data[key];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result); // { a: 'bar', c: 'faz'}
```